# Import Contribution - last step no longer goes to 'Summary / Error' report

Tags: contributions, import

We recently updated to CiviCRM 5.23.1

In the prior version when running it would run through the 4 documented stages
 1. Upload Data
 2. Match fields
 3. Preview
 4. Summary

But in 5.23.1  the summary stage no longer displays

As Summary is still staged as Step 4 - this looks like a bug - is this the case, and is there a fix to it?

Answer (score 3):

How large is your import? It seems to happen on larger imports and this has occurred on and off in Civi for some time in my experience. Something is causing it to hang.

You can still get to the summary page by replacing *Preview* with *Summary* in the URL. That will show you any records that could not be imported, etc. You can also look at MySQL and check that the import is done if the temporary table (civicrm_import_job...) is no longer there. If the table is still there, search status = NEW to find records not imported.

Yes, this is a workaround but it will get you on your way for the time-being.